# Opening .bcp files in R

Tags: r, bcp, file-conversion

I have been trying to convert UK charity commission data which is in .bcp file format into .csv file format which could then be read into R. The data I am referring to is available here: http://data.charitycommission.gov.uk/. What I am trying to do is turn these .bcp files into useable dataframes that I can clean and run analyses on in R.

There are suggestions on how to do this through python on this github page https://github.com/ncvo/charity-commission-extract but unfortunately I haven't been able to get these options to work.

I am wondering if there is any syntax or packages that will allow me to open these data in R directly? I haven't been able to find any.

Another option would be to simply open the files within R as a single character vector using `readLines`. I have done this and the files are delimited with `@**@` for columns and `*@@*` for rows. (See here: http://data.charitycommission.gov.uk/data-definition.aspx). Is there an R command that would allow me to create a dataframe from a long character string, defining de-limiters for both rows and columns?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive R solution, but I have experience with exactly that challenge on that dataset. Like so many issues it came down to character encoding - the Python scripts you linked to failed for me in Windows on certain rows, but I passed it somebody running Linux and it just worked.

Comment: Thanks for this - I couldn't get those python scripts to work in windows so I am glad it is not just me. I mostly work in R so I wondered if it was just my lack of ability in python, good to hear others have had issues.

Comment: Just use replace in subline text editor... replace `@**@` with `;`, and REGEX-replace `*@@*` with '\n'... save as csv.. not ypou can easily import using `fread` ofr your other favourite reader..

Comment: @Wimpel I did try in sublime text editor (I had tried to do the same thing in notepad++) but it crashed with the file size. Your solution below seems to do the trick though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R-solution

**edited version**

Not sure if all .bcp files are in the same format.. I downloaded the dataset you mentioned, and tried a solution for the smallest file; `extract_aoo_ref.bcp`

```
library(data.table)

#read the file as-is
text <- readChar("./extract_aoo_ref.bcp", 
                 nchars = file.info( "./extract_aoo_ref.bcp" )$size, 
                 useBytes = TRUE)
#replace column and row separator
text <- gsub( ";", ":", text)
text <- gsub( "@\\*\\*@", ";", text)
text <- gsub( "\\*@@\\*", "\n", text, perl = TRUE)
#read the results
result <- data.table::fread( text, 
                             header = FALSE, 
                             sep = ";", 
                             fill = TRUE, 
                             quote = "", 
                             strip.white = TRUE)

head(result,10)

#    V1 V2                           V3                                           V4 V5 V6
# 1:  A  1 THROUGHOUT ENGLAND AND WALES At least 10 authorities in England and Wales  N NA
# 2:  B  1             BRACKNELL FOREST                             BRACKNELL FOREST  N NA
# 3:  D  1                  AFGHANISTAN                                  AFGHANISTAN  N  2
# 4:  E  1                       AFRICA                                       AFRICA  N NA
# 5:  A  2           THROUGHOUT ENGLAND      At least 10 authorities in England only  N NA
# 6:  B  2               WEST BERKSHIRE                               WEST BERKSHIRE  N NA
# 7:  D  2                      ALBANIA                                      ALBANIA  N  3
# 8:  E  2                         ASIA                                         ASIA  N NA
# 9:  A  3             THROUGHOUT WALES        At least 10 authorities in Wales only  Y NA
# 10:  B  3                      READING                                      READING  N NA
```

same for the tricky file; `extract_charity.bcp`

```
head(result[,1:3],10)
#       V1 V2                                                                                 V3
# 1: 200000  0                                                          HOMEBOUND CRAFTSMEN TRUST
# 2: 200001  0                                                          PAINTERS' COMPANY CHARITY
# 3: 200002  0                                              THE ROYAL OPERA HOUSE BENEVOLENT FUND
# 4: 200003  0                                                          HERGA WORLD DISTRESS FUND
# 5: 200004  0 THE WILLIAM GOLDSTEIN LAY STAFF BENEVOLENT FUND (ROYAL HOSPITAL OF ST BARTHOLOMEW)
# 6: 200005  0                              DEVON AND CORNWALL ROMAN CATHOLIC DEVELOPMENT SOCIETY
# 7: 200006  0                                                    THE HORLEY SICK CHILDREN'S FUND
# 8: 200007  0                                            THE HOLDENHURST OLD PEOPLE'S HOME TRUST
# 9: 200008  0                                                         LORNA GASCOIGNE TRUST FUND
# 10: 200009  0                                          THE RALPH LEVY CHARITABLE COMPANY LIMITED
```

so.. looks like it is working :)

Comment: I was just testing a very similar approach in R. On Windows 10, your solution and mine work for extract_aoo_ref.csv, but for extract_charity.csv they both fail, which appears to be the Windows character encoding issues I mentioned in the initial comment. But I've upvoted as this is good solution and probably does work on Linux - the problem is with Windows' handling.

Comment: @MikeS it seemd to work if you use `useBytes = TRUE` in `readChar`.. Now the nasty error is gone... I updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like this works for me too, I have tried this on extract_partb.bcp and it looks like it works fine.

Comment: @Wimpel With extract_charity.bcp I still get an error. Looks this may be in the data itself though:


 `Error in data.table::fread(char_data, header = F, sep = ";", fill = TRUE) : 
Expecting 19 cols, but line 521 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=';' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.`

Comment: @SJPG I updates my answer, it now also works on `extract_charity.bcp`, see edited answer above... The offer I had to make, was to replace all `;` in the file with `:`. Than I could use the `;` as column separator later on... I also addes `quote=""` to the code, and removed leading and trailing whitespaces...   adjust to your own needs..

Comment: Thanks @wimpel! This whole approach is really helpful and has made it much easier. Before you suggested the approach above to get round this error, I found saving out a .txt file and importing the data into excel allowed me to deal with some of the tricky rows manually which was okay for my purposes. Thanks again for your help on this!